# Vertical radiator on single stud?

Tags: drywall, central-heating, radiator, drywall-anchor, brackets

I have an internal, decorated plasterboard wall (aka drywall outside UK) with poor studding: 120cm from its left end, there is a 22mm wide (i.e., as measured horizontally parallel to the wall) stud, then a 38mm stud (the two studs are spaced 60cm), then, after further 78cm, the jack stud of the door. I couldn't find other studs.
I need to hang a ~2500 BTUs radiator (I have gas central heating), and I'd prefer to avoid both hanging on plasterboard and adding battens/noggins to fix the brackets.

So I thought to fit a vertical radiator (total width 27cm, empty weight between 10 and 20 kg) by fixing all the four brackets to the 38mm stud via steel plates/flat brackets similar to this one:

[image]

More precisely, my idea is to fix to the 38mm stud the steel tee plate using its central holes, and then fix the two rad brackets one using the left holes on the tee, and the other using the right ones, symmetrically. Possibly, vertically aligning more than one tee on that same stud, and thereby avoiding anchoring directly on plasterboard.

Would that work and be doable?
Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Empty weight between 10 & 20 Kg is quite a range. Also, the weight of it will go up significantly when it's full of water. Be sure to keep that in mind when determining how many mounting brackets you'll be using. If the instructions don't indicate how much water the radiator will hold, you can easily measure by capping one end and filling from the other, then measuring how much you pour in before it overflows. Water weighs roughly 8lb/gallon or about 1kg/liter, so simple math should do the trick.

Comment: @FreeMan: thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Btw, 1l of water is exactly 1 kg :)

Comment: That's what I get for being American - my metric is rusty... :( It does make math _so_ much easier though!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason that won't work, *if*...

- The bracket is of sufficient gauge to provide the stiffness needed
- The screws are large enough; I'd use at least M6 x 35mm lag screws

I don't really know how metal is gauged in the metric world*. I'd guess 3mm or better, but you'll have to give it a twist and see what you think. If you can bend it by hand it's probably too light. I might even go heavier (or maybe to aluminum) and tap it for machine screws on the wings.

<sub>* Despite some statements on this network many U.S. citizens know metric quite well, and we wish we were fully metric. Actually, [we *are*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_States), officially. Sort of.</sub>